# NetApp and Hyper-V 2012 best practice/whitepapers?

Tags: netapp, hyper-v-server-2012

We've recently acquired a NetApp/Cisco UCS solution, and I'd like to gather some background knowledge as to the best practices when setting up Hyper-V 2012 on such a solution.

There is an upcoming seminar (in the Netherlands, http://www.realdolmen.com/nl/MSHyper-v-2012_NetApp), but it's in Dutch, and a couple of weeks away... Does anyone have some whitepapers/documentation about such a setup, or hasn't it been done before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are some useful NetAPP Links, Whitepapers etc. which will help you understand the solution offerings and features unique to NetAPP.

Create a Login (Free - But limited) on [NetAPP Communities](http://communities.netapp.com)
This will allow you to interact with the community and or ask NetAPP related questions

If you are a netapp customer, you would or you should then be able to get a "NOW" Login which will let you browse some restricted areas of the site only for customers etc.

---

WhitePapers and other useful Links :
NetAPP publishes Technical Report known as TR Documents, for most of the famous platforms like Hyper-V, VMWare etc.

[NetAPP-Microsoft Private Cloud Fast Track](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/8/B/F8BD6178-074C-42B1-98EB-AB9AAD71537E/NetApp_Private-Cloud-Fast_Track_Document.pdf)

[NetAPP Communities - Microsoft Solutions](https://communities.netapp.com/docs/DOC-15513)
[NetAPP for Microsoft Environments](https://communities.netapp.com/community/netapp-blogs/msenviro/content)
[NetAPP - Hyper-V - Cisco UCS - Cloud Fast Track Document](http://www.netapp.com/templates/mediaView?m=wp-7132.pdf&cc=us&wid=121768854&mid=121768854)
[Netapp hyper v storage best practices](http://www.netapp.com/us/library/technical-reports/tr-3702.html)

Do read the following Documents whenever you have some time
[NetAPP Analyst Reports, WhitePapers, Customer Stories, Research Papers, **Technical Reports (TR Documents)**](http://www.netapp.com/us/library/)

---

Most important, if you are going to Manage the Storage in your organisation then you should read about the Brain of a NetAPP Box, the Data ONTAP Operating System, current release is 8.1.1 (i think).

Data ONTAP operates in 2 Modes :
a) 7-Mode (Stand Alone Mode but with Dual Controllers / Heads (if Purchased) which make it a HA-Pair.

b) Cluster Mode or C-Mode (In this mode you can add multiple NetAPP controllers to form a cluster and all underlying storage is then very flexible to manage providing seamless data movement and other great benefits.

**[Data ONTAP Documentation](http://support.netapp.com/documentation/productlibrary/index.html?productID=30092)**

Hope this helps

Comment: Also read this - might be helpful : http://www.netapp.com/templates/mediaView?m=wp-7132.pdf&cc=us&wid=121768854&mid=121768854